# How to get the sum of particular array of object property based on some flag in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have one below an array of objects and I need a total sum. So, the condition we have to add the sum, the moment we same id and loc and isUpdated should true in of them then only we have to add the sum property.
So, if it isUpdate truea and it's match id and loc then we have to add sum property it doesn't matter if the isUpdated flag is false in another object which contain the same id and loc property.

```js
let arrayObj = [
    {
        id: 123,
        loc: "ABC",
        sum: 100,
        isUpdated: true
    },
    {
        id: 123,
        loc: "ABC",
        sum: 200,
        isUpdated: false
    },

    {
        id: 235,
        loc: "FBC",
        sum: 400,
        isUpdated: true
    },
    {
        id: 236,
        loc: "YBC",
        sum: 100,
        isUpdated: false
    }
]
```

My Output would be something like this

ABC - sum : 300
FBC - sum : 400

Comment: Your question is really messy. Can you please clean it up a bit, and share the code you tried running? An example is needed here. Where are you stuck?

Comment: If the `id` is part of the key, I don't understand why it is not in your desired output;

Comment: You can use reduce()

Answer (score 0):

I made a function `sumBy` for you. Pass it the property you want to sum and the arrayObj data to get the sum by that property.

```js
let arrayObj = [ { id: 123, loc: "ABC", sum: 100, isUpdated: true }, { id: 123, loc: "ABC", sum: 200, isUpdated: false }, { id: 235, loc: "FBC", sum: 400, isUpdated: true }, { id: 236, loc: "YBC", sum: 100, isUpdated: false } ]

const sumBy = (prop, array) => array.reduce(
  (sum, obj) => obj.loc === prop ? sum + obj.sum : sum,
  0,
)

console.log('ABC -', sumBy('ABC', arrayObj))

console.log('FBC -', sumBy('FBC', arrayObj))
```

Comment: I need solution based on isUpdated flag, if it is true, then check whether id and loc is getting matched or not then return the sum if it is match with another array of object doesn't matter other array of object have isUpdated flag false

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a variant of the data which includes the key as a string (`id` and `loc` combined in JSON format)

Then aggregate the data with the use of a Map keyed by those keys:

- Aggregate the `sum` values by taking their sum
- Aggregate the `isUpdated` values by taking the logical OR

Finally extract those objects from the map and filter them by `isUpdated`:

```js
let arrayObj = [ { id: 123, loc: "ABC", sum: 100, isUpdated: true },{ id: 123, loc: "ABC", sum: 200, isUpdated: false },{ id: 235, loc: "FBC", sum: 400, isUpdated: true }, { id: 236, loc: "YBC", sum: 100, isUpdated: false }];

// Add the key
let keyed = arrayObj.map(o => ({ key: JSON.stringify([o.id, o.loc]), ...o }));
// Create a map by key for sums
let map = new Map(keyed.map(({key, id, loc }) => [key, { id, loc, sum: 0 }]));
// accumulate sum and isUpdated
for (let o of keyed) {
    let acc = map.get(o.key);  
    acc.sum += o.sum; 
    acc.isUpdated ||= o.isUpdated;
}
// Extract accumulated objects and filter by isUpdated
let result = Array.from(map.values()).filter(o => o.isUpdated);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const arrayObj = [ { id: 123, loc: "ABC", sum: 100, isUpdated: true }, { id: 123, loc: "ABC", sum: 200, isUpdated: false },
{ id: 235, loc: "FBC", sum: 400, isUpdated: true }, { id: 236, loc: "YBC", sum: 100, isUpdated: false } ];

const retAux = arrayObj.filter(item => item.isUpdated === true );
const ret = retAux.map(item =>  arrayObj
.filter(aObj => aObj.id === item.id && aObj.loc === item.loc)
.reduce((prevVal, {sum}) =>  {return prevVal + sum;},0));

console.log(ret);
```